# Правильность написания слова Устав

Tags: прописная-строчная

Как правильно написать слово устав в преамбуле договора с маленькой или большой буквы?
Пример: "Иванов С.И., именуемый в дальнейшем «Жертвователь», с одной стороны, и ООО "Молл", именуемое в дальнейшем «Одаряемый», в лице директора Степановой С.С., действующей на основании **устава**, с другой стороны, именуемые вместе «стороны», заключили настоящий договор (далее - договор) о нижеследующем".

Answer (score 2):

***Д.Э. Розенталь. "Справочник по русскому языку. Прописная или строчная?"***

устав: Дисциплинарный устав Вооружённых Сил РФ, Консульский устав РФ, Корабельный устав Военно-Морского Флота РФ...; ***но в начале названия:*** Устав ООН, Устав профессиональных союзов, Устав Союза журналистов России
Устав гарнизонной и караульной служб Вооружённых Сил РФ

**Думаю, что слово *устав* в данном контексте можно оформить со строчной, так как полного названия устава здесь нет и слово не является "родовым" в данном договоре. Если же слово Устав находится в начале полного названия этого устава, тогда используется прописная буква.**

*Чтобы текст документа имел однозначное толкование, нужно сначала ввести сокращение (образовать «родовое» слово), а потом употреблять его по тексту. Чтобы оно бросалось в глаза, его часто оформляют с прописной (большой) буквы:
Источник: http://www.delo-press.ru/questions.php?n=18227* - Здесь есть оба варианта написания *Устав - устав*

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сначала привести полное наименование устава, на который будут ссылки (чтобы никто впоследствии не говорил, что "этого нет в Уставе караульной службы"), при этом указать в скобках его условное сокращённое наименование (далее - "Устав"). То же с "Договором". Пример:

http://www.transneft.ru/u/tenders_file/2137392/proekt_dogovora.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что данный вопрос по оформлению контракта относится к тематике сайта (то есть, что ответ на него регламентируется правилами русского языка), но попытаюсь ответить на конкретном примере.

Я смотрю сейчас на контракт между двумя крупнейшими транснациональными компаниями, который выверили юристы международного уровня с обеих сторон. Слово "Устав" написано с большой буквы и никакой расшифровки не имеет (считается само собой разумеющимся, наверное; в любом случае, я ни в одном контракте не встречал такую расшифровку — даже в примере из другого ответа), и слово "Стороны" написано без кавычек, но с прописной буквы.

Если требуется ссылка на нормативы по этому вопросу, я бы предложил обратиться к юристам.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь лучше заглавная. Я понимаю чувства ревнителей правописания, безуспешно борющихся с засильем неуместных заглавных букв, но у нас не тот случай. К тому же вынужден слегка подискутировать с авторами других ответов.

Подобные конструкции относятся к условным именам собственным, означая не просто устав, а единичный конкретный устав данной организации, заменяя подобным способом название устава и, таким образом, превращаясь в некое имя собственное (оним).

Более того, у вас ниже по  тексту идет упоминание сторон договора. Так вот, в безупречно канцелярском стиле это часть выглядела бы так: "именуемые в дальнейшем Стороны". *Стороны* - тоже оним, подобный рассмотренному Уставу.
А еще - Жертвователь и Одаряемый - тоже условные имена собственные *(и даже не очень понятно, нужно  ли их забирать в преамбуле в кавычки)*.

Других замечание по грамматике у оформлению у меня нет. Все остальное - в лучших традициях документооборота. Вопрос о грамматическом роде директора здесь решается простым соображением, что действует **лицо**, а не должность.

***"Иванов С. И., именуемый в дальнейшем «Жертвователь», с одной стороны, и ООО "Молл", именуемое в дальнейшем «Одаряемый», в лице директора Степановой С. С., действующей на основании Устава, с другой стороны, именуемые в дальнейшем Стороны, заключили настоящий договор (далее - договор) о нижеследующем".***

Answer (score 0):

"Иванов С.И., именуемый в дальнейшем «Жертвователь», с одной стороны, и ООО "Молл", именуемое в дальнейшем «Одаряемый», в лице директора Степановой С.С., действующей на основании **Устава**, с другой стороны, именуемые вместе «стороны»...

Я думаю так:

Директор организации действует на основании **имеющегося Устава этой организации** (в тексте дана ссылка на  документ, который пишется с прописной буквы).

Вот здесь есть пример такой записи: [http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=действующей](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Вопрос № 288792
Добрый день. Руководитель нашей организации - женщина. В связи с этим возникает вопрос о том, как писать в договорах. В лице президента фонда ...., действующей **на основании Устава**? Или действующего на основании Устава?