# Первая поправка — с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как пишется словосочетание "первая поправка", если речь идет о поправке к Конституции США? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ох и непростой вопрос это. Но все-таки лучше с заглавной.

Тут есть предмет для серьезного спора, поскольку в общих правилах нет прямого указания на то, как должны  писаться все подобные сочетания, представляющие собой так называемые "условные имена собственные" (онимы), тут много от контекста зависит, но все-таки примеры написания с заглавной есть (вот тут один такое обсуждался - [Правильность написания слова Устав](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449732)). Так что, думаю, ради наглядности и осмысленности текста стоит использовать именно заглавную, подчеркивая уникальность объекта.

Правда, тут еще исторический фон... О первых Поправках (десяти, кажется), вошедших в "Билль о правах", вспоминают довольно редко в отрыве от самого Билля... Про Четырнадцатую или Семнадцатую не знает только ленивый - и всегда можно сослаться на закрепившееся написание. Хотя и этот факт можно двояко толковать... В общем, беру грех на душу - рекомендую заглавную.