# В каких случаях слово «закон» пишется с прописной буквы?

Tags: прописная-строчная, прописная

Например, «Согласно Закону "О пенсионном обеспечении Республики Казахстан"» или «Согласно закону "О пенсионном обеспечении Республики Казахстан"»?

Хотелось бы, чтобы в ответе было приведено конкретное правило русского языка, касающееся этого вопроса.

Comment: Здесь про слово "Устав", но все то же самоме. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449732

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильность написания слова Устав](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449732/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2)

Comment: Всё же закон и устав – совершенно разные нормативные акты. Первый – уровня государства, второй – локальный. Насчет устава у меня никаких сомнений и не было, а «закон» пишут кто во что горазд, и хотелось бы именно правило русского языка, касающееся конкретно слова «закон».

Comment: правила не пишут на каждое конкретное слово. Есть общий принцип, что имена собственные пишутся с заглавной буквы. И не надо требовать отдельное "правило" для Пети и Маши, хотя имена разные.

Comment: Я согласна, что правила не пишут на каждое конкретное слово. Но юридическая сфера очень специфична.

Comment: Ну да, есть такое. Только специфичность не в том, чтобы на каждое слово искать свое правило искать, а в том, что юристам правила русского языка - вообще не указ. Сталкивался много раз.

Comment: А вот что касается казахского русского... Ну наверняка там есть свои заморочки - именно по части правил заглавная/строчная и подобного. Просто не знаю наверняка, какие именно. Но вот для информации: в "украинском русском" после инициала с точкой пробел не делается.  Узаконили еще при Ющенке, дай Бог  им всем здоровья! ))) Справляться по таким вещам надо на месте, у своих законников.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово "**закон**" не является исключением из следующего правила.

[**§ 18. Названия документов, памятников старины, произведений искусства, органов печати, информационных агентств и др.**](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=22)

> 1. В составных названиях важнейших документов, государственных законов **первое слово** (и все имена собственные) пишется с прописной буквы: *Декрет о мире, Договор о дружбе, сотрудничестве и взаимной помощи.*

Таким образом, ecли cлoвo "зaкoн" являeтcя пepвым cлoвoм в нaзвaнии гocдoкyмeнтa, тo oнo пишeтcя c пpoпиcнoй бyквы:

*Согласно **Закону** "О пенсионном обеспечении Республики Казахстан".*

B ocтaльныx cлyчaяx дaннoe cлoвo пишeтcя co cтpoчнoй бyквы: *Фeдepaльный **зaкoн** вcтyпил в cилy.*

> **Вопрос № 275330**
>
> Добрый день! Срочно надо, ответьте, пожалуйста! Как правильно - Закон о... или закон "О... Благодарю!
>
> [**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&start=15)
>
> Написание зависит от того, нужно ли привести официальное название документа. Ср.: *Федеральный закон Российской Федерации «О государственном языке Российской Федерации»* (официальное название) и *закон о русском языке* (неофициально о том же самом законе).

P. S. Сочетание "пенсионное обеспечение Республики" некорректно. Ср.: *Федеральный закон "О государственном пенсионном обеспечении **в** Российской Федерации".* И вот как раз [**ссылка на сайт**](https://online.zakon.kz/m/document/?doc_id=34583542), где "Ваш" закон написан с большой буквы, а в названии присутствует предлог ***в***.

Comment: Спасибо. А «Федеральный» в сочетании со словом «закон», получается, в любом случае пишется с прописной?

Comment: @YuiiyaVlady Нет, тоже не всегда. Если в официальном использовании, с полным наименованием закона, тогда с большой. Примеры можете посмотреть по ссылке в ответе с Грамоты.ру.

Comment: @YuiiyaVlady  "например, в газетной статье: _фермеры с нетерпением ждут принятия **федерального** закона о мясе"_.

Comment: Всё понятно, спасибо!