# Усечённые наименования — с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Допустимо ли написание усечённых наименований с прописной буквы (при официальном и неофициальном употреблении) в предложениях:

1. Антимонопольный комитет, рассмотрев судебное дело № такой-то о нарушении законодательства о защите экономической конкуренции (далее — Дело), установил следующее...
2. Одним из видов имущественных налогов является налог на недвижимое имущество, не являющееся земельным участком (далее — Налог).
3. Для разговорного стиля речи (далее — Разговорный стиль) характерно употребление разговорной, просторечной и эмоционально окрашенной лексики (вместе далее — Разговорная лексика).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В официальном стиле - это нормально. Именно с прописной такие вещи и пишут.
Только это не "усеченные наименования", а ***условные имена собственные***.

> В текстах официальных сообщений, договоров и т. п. условные
> имена собственные пишутся с прописной буквы: Высокие Договаривающиеся
> Стороны — в актах международного значения, Чрезвычайный и Полномочный
> Посол — в официальном сообщении; Автор, Издательство — в авторском
> договоре.

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=30

Еще подробности - см. здесь.
[Правильность написания слова Устав](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449732)

Что касается вашего третьего пункта, то под вопросом, тут контекст нужен. Даже если автор впервые вводит это понятие, то применение заглавной сомнительно, поскольку стиль текста претендует разве что на научный, но никак не на официальный.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что при неофициальном употреблении, в том числе в научном стиле, введение "условных имен собственных" избыточно?